# SonarQube shows error even when implemented the suggestions

Tags: java, sonarqube, apache-httpclient-4.x, static-code-analysis

On doing a code analysis of the below code in SonarQube, I found that i suggests to close the HttpClient.

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;

public void request() {
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = null;

    try {
        httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        /**
         * Rest of the code
         */
    } catch(IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error in processing : {}", e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if(httpclient != null) {
                httpclient.close();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error in closing client : {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

SonarQube still complains that `httpclient` should be closed, even though I am closing it in the `finally` block.

The error given by SonarQube:

`Close this "CloseableHttpClient".`

Java - 1.8
SonarQube - 5.6

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Your question misses details about product versions used. Especially, which version of [SonarJava](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarJava) ?

Comment: Still missing version of [SonarJava](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarJava) (Java Plugin deployed in your SonarQube server)

Comment: @Nicolas - v1.8

Comment: v1.8 looks more like a Java version, then the version of Java Plugin ([latest is v4.4](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarJava), v1.8 would be an ancient/incompatible version). Can you check in your [SonarQube Update Center](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Update+Center) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a try with resources

```
public void request() {
   try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()){
    /**
     * Rest of the code
     */
   } catch(IOException e) {
       LOGGER.error("Error in processing : {}", e.getMessage(), e);
   } 
}
```